# Does Omniture use Third Party Cookies for Tracking?

Tags: analytics, adobe-analytics

Does Omniture use third party cookies to track users' activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Amateur Barista,
Omniture SiteCatalyst use by Default Third Party Cookie, but if you need you can use First Party Cookie.
To do that you need to ask Omniture Client Care for some module and later you will have to buy 1 or 2 Security Certificate.

All is very simple.
Claudio

Comment: Note that if you don't have SSL tracking on your site, you don't have to purchase any security certificates. In fact, it's amazingly easy to set it up- just change the s.trackingServer to point to a subdomain dedicated for cookies (e.g. stats.mysite.com), then forward your stats.mysite.com to where the third-party cookies are being used (usually a subdomain of 112.2o7.net or 122.2o7.net).

There's an awesome white paper that gives you step-by-step instructions on how to do this; just search 'fpc' in the SiteCatalyst interface and it will be the first search result.